# How to display visitor's country flag depending on the visitor's IP address?

Tags: location

How can I display **Visitor**'s country name and flag and depending on his IP address in a block?

Answer (score 2):

The [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module can give you the user's IP address. The following code should give you a block, assuming you have flag images whose file names match the country code, e.g. "ie.png" for Ireland and those file are in "/sites/default/images".

```
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['flag'] = array(
    'info' => t('Country flag')
  return $blocks;
}
function mymodule_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'flag' :
      $block['content'] = _flag_block_view();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
function _flag_block_view() {

  // Get the IP address
  $smart_ip_session = smart_ip_session_get('smart_ip');
  if ($smart_ip_session['location']['country_code']) {
     $code =  $smart_ip_session['location']['country_code'];
     $output = '<img src="/sites/default/files/images/' . strtolower($code) . '.png />';

  else {
    $output = "Nothing";
  }
  return $output;
}
```

The above is a simplistic solution. In practice you might want to make better provision for country codes and/or flag images not being available,  add alt and/or title attributes to your  tag, etc.

Also bear in mind you will need to choose a source of IP geolocation data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php/3650102#3650102) for info on that. And, remember geolocation data is not guaranteed to be 100% accurate.